# Tensorflow results have the following form <tf.Tensor 'Add:0' shape=() dtype=int32>

Tags: linux, installation, tensorflow, anaconda

After installing Tensorflow, when I try to add to numbers with `tf.add(2,3)` for example, it only returns `tf.Tensor 'Add:0' shape=() dtype=int32` instead of a result. I installed Tensorflow with Anaconda on a Linux 64-bit. How can I get a result (e.g. 5)?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is a symbolic computation library, so once you call the 'add' function, you get a symbolic variable, not the final output. You have to run it using a session to get the output. In your case, the code will be:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
c = tf.add(2,3)
sess.run(c)
```

Check out [TF Introduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/index.html) for more details